# Symfony2, Typeahead, form collection

Tags: javascript, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig, typeahead.js

I have this section of Javascript for a form collection in Symfony2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create Input Text
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add[data-target]', function(event) {

    event && event.preventDefault();

    var collectionHolder = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target'));

    if (!collectionHolder.attr('data-counter')) {
      collectionHolder.attr('data-counter', collectionHolder.children().length);
    }

    var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');
    var form = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, collectionHolder.attr('data-counter'));

    collectionHolder.attr('data-counter', Number(collectionHolder.attr('data-counter')) + 1);
    collectionHolder.append(form);

    typeInitialize();

    return false;

  });

  // Remove Input Text
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove[data-related]', function(event) {

    event && event.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).attr('data-related');

    ($('*[data-content="'+ name +'"]')).remove();

  });

  // Initialize Typeahead
  function typeInitialize() {

    // Create typeahead instance
    var url = Routing.generate('ajax_search', {name: 'WILDCARD'});
    // Trigger typeahead + bloodhound
    var products = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      identify: function(obj) { return obj.u_name; },
      prefetch: 'json/result.json',
      remote: {
        url: url,
        wildcard: 'WILDCARD',
      }
    });

    products.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
      minLength: 3,
      highlight: true,
      limit: 10,
    },
    {
      name: 'product',
      display: 'u_name',
      source: products.ttAdapter()
    });
  }
});
```

The Twig Template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
{% macro widget_prototype(widget, remove_text) %}
{% if widget.vars.prototype is defined %}
    {% set form = widget.vars.prototype %}
    {% set name = widget.vars.prototype.vars.full_name %}
{% else %}
    {% set form = widget %}
    {% set name = widget.vars.full_name %}
{% endif %}
<div data-content="{{ name }}">
    <div class="btn-remove">
      <a class="btn-remove" data-related="{{ name }}">{{ remove_text }}</a>
    </div>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
</div>
{% endmacro %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <a class="btn-add" class="clicked" data-target="post_tags">Adauga Produs</a>
    {{form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}})}}
    {{form_row(form.name)}}
    <div id="post_tags" data-prototype="{{ _self.widget_prototype(form.product, 'Delete Product')|escape }}">
        {% for widget in form.product.children %}
            {{ _self.widget_prototype(widget, 'Delete Product') }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {{form_end(form)}}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The code doesn't contain any errors been testing it all day long, but when I try to add a new field it adds it with no problem and the second field it adds the second field but on the first field it adds an empty span from `typeahead` then when I add the third field it adds another  empty span to the first element. On forth field it adds to the first second and third input an empty span for `typeahead`.
From what I believe, the problem is from `typeInitialize` function and how I call it, but I couldn't figure it out myself what I did wrong on this part and then the second problem is when I click on remove it removes all the inputs that I added.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the entire code fixed the problems. Here is the updated version for anyone who needs it.

```
// setup an "add a tag" link
var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add_tag_link">Adauga Produs</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('#post_tags').append($addTagLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
   var $collectionHolder = $('#post_tags');

    // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
    $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see code block below)
        addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);

        typeInitialize();
    });


});

function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '$$name$$' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<div class="post_tags"></div>').append(newForm);

    // also add a remove button, just for this example
    $newFormLi.append('<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning remove-tag">Sterge Produsul</a>');

    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

    // handle the removal, just for this example
    $('.remove-tag').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().remove();

        return false;
    });
}
// Initialize Typeahead
function typeInitialize() {

  // Create typeahead instance
  var url = Routing.generate('ajax_search', {name: 'WILDCARD'});
  // Trigger typeahead + bloodhound
  var products = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    identify: function(obj) { return obj.u_name; },
    prefetch: 'json/result.json',
    remote: {
      url: url,
      wildcard: 'WILDCARD',
    }
  });

  products.initialize();



  $('.post_tags').find('input[type=text]:last').typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    highlight: true,
    limit: 10,
  },
  {
    name: 'product',
    display: 'u_name',
    source: products.ttAdapter()
  }).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
  });
}
```